# MVC: How to retain values in Model after an [HttpPost]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

The first line of my controller is initalizing my model:

```
ViewModel myModel = new ViewModel;

public ActionResult MyPage(string id)
{
  var concatString = id.Split(',');
  myModel.newString1 = concatString [0];
  myModel.newString2 = concatString [1];
  myModel.newString3 = concatString [2];
  return View(meterModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyPage()
{
  ValidateStuff(Request);
  return View(myModel)
}

private void ValidateSuff(HttpRequestBase request)
{
  //Below is basic summery of regexmatching of form fields
  if (request.form[Stuff1] != "")
  {
    myModel.string4 = request.form[Stuff1];
  }
  else
  {
    ModelState.AddModelError("Stuff1", "Required Field.");
  }
}
```

I am passing 50% of the information to that model from another controller (This works fine), and need the other 50% from a form I generated. During the HttpPost however the model re-initializes and I lost the first 50% of my object values...

Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Difficult to understand why your doing this (why are you not posting back your model?). Your post method only ever sets the values of `newString4`, `newString5` and `newString6` (it never sets the values of the first 3 properties so of course they are null - your field`myModel` is initialized with each request).

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke - Have the form write to the model in the view? then pass the model back?, I guess I left out that I am taking the form, and validating the data in the controller.. I will update the main topic

Comment: Yes, but why does you model not just contain properties for `Stuff1`, `Stuff2` etc and let the framework take care of the binding for you - `public ActionResult MyPage(ViewModel model)` (and get rid of that  awful `request.form[Stuff1];` code

Comment: As this is my first mvc project, I was under the impression that you should only right validated or "good" values to the model.

Comment: Everything you have shown here can be done better (and with less code) by using the features of MVC including applying validation attributes to your properties (e.g. `[Required]`), using strongly typed html helpers to bind your properties, using client side validation and posting back your model and checking `if(ModelState.IsValid) {...`). If you post you model and the view I can give an answer that explains this better

Comment: I was about to give you an answer based on the previous edit (using `MeterViewModel`) but now you have deleted it? Was that what you were trying to do or is it another model?